# Amazon web services S3 and EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, buckets

I can set up my EC2 instances so that certain users other than myself are allowed to SSH in. Is there anyway of achieving a similar situation with S3 in giving certain users access to buckets without revealing the Access ID and Secret keys?

Thanks for any help.

Max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the method to do this is described in the [Access Control Lists](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/index.html?S3_ACLs.html) documentation.

Note that when using ACLs, the other users to whom you grant permissions must have their own Amazon S3 account. If your users don't have their own account, see:

- [How to restrict Amazon S3 API access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856988/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-api-access)
- [Amazon S3 permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765964/amazon-s3-permissions)